# Why does using Same "For loop" in different class gave me different output in Java?

Tags: java

This is just pattern creating program in java using for loop. When I copy pasted the program directly from the website for the first class `Pattern` I got the right output. but when I tried to type the same program on my own without any changes in the second class `Pattern22` I'm getting a different output.

```
public class Pattern {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i, j, row = 6;
        for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
                System.out.print("* ");

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

The output I Got for the first class `Pattern`.

```
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * * 
* * * * * 
* * * * * * 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

This is the Second class I created which gave wrong output.

```
public class Pattern22 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i, j, row = 6;
        for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
                System.out.println("* ");

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

The output I got for the Second class `Pattern22`.

```
* 

* 
* 

* 
* 
* 

* 
* 
* 
* 

* 
* 
* 
* 
* 

* 
* 
* 
* 
* 
* 


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Why I'm I getting different output for same for loop? I checked both the codes side by side both codes are same but ended getting different output.

Comment: It’s not the same - there’s a key difference. Think about why the patterns differ and then examine the code to see where it is.

Comment: They're not the same.  print vs println

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`println` moves the cursor to new line in the console.

```
public class Pattern22 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i, j, row = 6;
        for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j <= i; j++)
                System.out.print("* ");

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```